# Measure effectiveness of recommendation engine with implicit rating

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, precision-recall

Say a company has an eCommerce platform that includes a recommendation engine. As a user adds items to his/her cart, they are provided with suggestions for other items that the user might also want to add. The rating scale is implicit and binary - did the user add the item or not (`0` = `no`, `1` = `yes`). The company has trained a few different models and wants to understand how they are performing.

What are some metrics the company could use? and how would they go about calculating such metrics in this situation?

Comment: If there is no good answer within the next few hours, I suggest you consider posting a more detailed version of the question to the CrossValidated community (they specialize in statistics and machine learning).

Comment: Will do thanks! I'll give it a little longer.